# alternative for range and len functions

Tags: python, string, function

In the For loop below

```
def __str__(self):
    output = " "
    for i in range(len(self)):
        output += (self.str_data[i] +" ")
    return  output
```

How may I rewrite this **without** using range & len or any other **inbuilt** **function**?

PS: str_data was used as instance variable of type list in *init* earlier.

Comment: do u not want to use any builtin function or only range and len

Comment: no built in functions to be used including range() and len(). I need a substitute for them here in _str_

Answer (score 2):

If you're *allowed* to use [join()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) then you could do:

```
def __str__(self):
    return " ".join(self.str_data)
```

*This is of course assuming `len(self)` would result in the same as `len(self.str_data)`.*

To result in exactly the same as your loop it would actually have to be:

```
def __str__(self):
    if self.str_data:
        return " " + " ".join(self.str_data) + " "
    else:
        return " "
```

Comment: @ Vallentin : I am not allowed to use join or any other inbuilt function as such.

Comment: @phoenix_9 what are you allowed to use then?

Comment: Anything sans inbuilt functions. If you are able to tweak and twist the above code a bit , works fine for me. But just avoid the inbuilt function(s)

Answer (score 0):

**New Answer:** (no builtin functions)

```
def __str__(self):
    output=""
    for i in self.str_data:
         output+=i+" "
    return output
```

**Old Answer :**

asterisk and double asterisk can be used within list, tuple, set and dictionary, * will unpack list/tuple and ** will unpack dictionary.

```
my_array = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
print(*my_array) # unpacking list
```

Another method using join:

```
print(' '.join(map(str,my_array)))
```

Output

```
0 1 2 3 4 5
```

For the given question:

Since return keyword returns only one argument we can't unpack the list and we have to use function

```
def __str__(self):  
    return ' '.join(self.str_data)
```

Comment: You know, you shouldn't just copy every answer into your own.

Comment: @Vallentin Sorry, I assumed that the list consist of string literals since the OP didn't use str().And also forget that i can edit someone answers

Answer (score 0):

You mean like this ?

```
class A(object):

    def __init__(self, str_data):
        self.str_data = str_data

    def __str__(self):
        return " ".join(str(s) for s in self)

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.str_data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(A(["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]))
```

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer is perfectly fine (if you omit builtins), but here's a closer version to what you did:

```
output = ""
array = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
for i in array:
   output += "%s " % (i)
output = output[:-1]
return output
```

Please note that I change the way you set your output, as I think in order to get the result you want. Like you asked it does not use any builtin and it works just fine.

Comment: OP isn't allowed to use `join()`, so I'm assuming OP is neither allowed to use `format()`. I would however assume that changing it to `i + " "` would be enough (in relation to OP not being *allowed* to use built-in functions).

Comment: Good catch, let me change that! Do you want to directly suggest an edit that I'll then accept?

Comment: Thanks @JoeBeCool, but unfortunately format is an inbuilt function. https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html

Comment: The catch is that if `str_data` contains something that doesn't get implicitly converted to a string, then that would be a problem. `str(i)` would be the solution, but OP for whatever reason isn't allowed to use built-in functions!

Comment: Ok, how about now? No builtins

Answer (score 0):

```
import json

def __str__(self):
    output = json.dumps(self.str_data)
    output = output[1:-1].replace(',', ' ')
    return  output
```

For your consideration.

Comment: I Cant import any module for my case.

Answer (score 0):

You could use highlevel functions like

```
" ".join(map(lambda x:x+" ",self.str_data))
```

map applies the function to add a space to each string in `self.str_data` and `" ".join` adds each of those to the starting string.

But of course these are built-in functions, it's just a really clean solution.

Answer (score 0):

Alternitive to len() could be for loop - like:

```
var1 = 0
for var2 in list1:
 var1 += 1
```